# Git: best way to remove all changes from a given file for one branch

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-merge, git-branch

I have a bit of a messy branch with 20 or so commits, and I'm preparing for a merge back to master. I've rebased it off master, and looking closer, I realise that there are files being modified in ways that are totally irrelevant to this branch, and not ready to be committed. The changes to those files aren't confined to specific commits.

So basically, I don't want anything to do with those files to be included in this branch if possible. Is there a good way to go about this? My fall back position #1 is obviously to just copy over the latest copy of each of those files then commit. But then the history will still contain the changes, and the Git Gods will frown upon me.

Fall back position #2 is to do the same, then squash the whole branch history down to one commit.

Any improvements on these?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Say your history is

```
$ git lola
* 6473d7f (master) Update
| * 9bcfa7e (HEAD, topic) Munge a, b, and c
| * 99af942 Munge b and c
| * 8383e2c Munge a and b
|/
* d1363f4 Baseline
```

Note: [`lola`](http://blog.kfish.org/2010/04/git-lola.html) is a non-standard but helpful alias.

The commits have modified three different files.

```
$ git log --decorate=short --pretty=oneline --name-status topic
9bcfa7e946a92c226ad50ce430a9e4ae55b32490 (HEAD, topic)
M       a
M       b
M       c
99af942dbb922effcad8a72e96bec9ee9afcc437 Munge b and c
M       b
M       c
8383e2c8d6092550fec13d3c888c037b3a68af15 Munge a and b
M       a
M       b
d1363f4fba67d94999b269b51bdb50a8a68ba27a Baseline
A       a
A       b
A       c
```

The changes to file `b` are the ones you want to keep, and you want to discard all changes to `a` and `c`. One way to do this is with [`git filter-branch`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-filter-branch.html).

```
$ git checkout -b tmp topic
Switched to a new branch 'tmp'

$ git merge-base topic master
d1363f4fba67d94999b269b51bdb50a8a68ba27a

$ git filter-branch --tree-filter 'git checkout d1363f -- a c' master..tmp
Rewrite 8383e2c8d6092550fec13d3c888c037b3a68af15 (1/3)
Rewrite 99af942dbb922effcad8a72e96bec9ee9afcc437 (2/3)
Rewrite 9bcfa7e946a92c226ad50ce430a9e4ae55b32490 (3/3)
Ref 'refs/heads/tmp' was rewritten
```

The tree filter above checks out the commits in the named range and restores files `a` and `c` to the content at the “merge base,” that is, the commit at which `topic` branched away from `master`.

Now `tmp` has all `topic`’s changes to `b` but no changes to any other file.

```
$ git log --decorate --pretty=oneline --name-status tmp
9ee7e2bd2f380cc338b0264686bcd6f071eb1087 (HEAD, tmp) Munge a, b, and c
M       b
226c22f150af1ddc1f9adc19f97fc4f220851ada Munge b and c
M       b
45e706f7b22c37ee2025ee0d04c651135e7b31cd Munge a and b
M       b
d1363f4fba67d94999b269b51bdb50a8a68ba27a Baseline
A       a
A       b
A       c
```

As a safety measure, `git filter-branch` stores a backup of your original ref. When you’re satisfied with your changes and want to delete the backup `tmp`, run

```
$ git update-ref -d refs/original/refs/heads/tmp
```

Comment: +1 Excellent answer. Using filter-branch is such an amazing tool once you wrap your head around it.

Comment: Lots of great stuff in here I'm still digesting. 'log --name-status <branch>' is cool.

Comment: Buh. I followed all the steps of this excellent answer, and everything went swimmingly until the end of the filter-branch. "WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/tmp' is unchanged". Checking the history, the file modifications are still there, and none of the commit ids have changed (as far as I can tell), even though git reported "rewriting" them all. Hmm.

Comment: Ah. Weirdly the argument to "git checkout" was treated as case-sensitive (even though I'm on Windows). It's now worked. Running that "git log" command is now strange in two ways: it still lists the file as modified (even though there are no changes to it in the diff), and the old commit id is retained (but shown in yellow now). Scary command!

Comment: Err, next question: how does one restore from that backup, that I see in refs/original/heads/...

Comment: @SteveBennett Take your pick. Run `git reflog` or `git for-each-ref` to get the old branch's SHA-1. Resurrect the old branch with `git checkout -b old refs/original/refs/heads/tmp` or `git checkout -b $sha1`.

Answer (score 1):

To checkout to a specific version you can do
`git checkout <sha1> <file>`
where `sha1` is the unique sha1 hash of that version you want the file to be in.

Comment: curious if you check in a file restored in this fashion on a branch - if it essentially removes any changes of that file from the branch history?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a couple of problems as Windows user:

1. Use Double Quotes for --tree-filter command.
2. Use forward slashes for filepath.
3. Dont start filepath with forward slash.

Here is how my command ended up looking:

```
git filter-branch -f --tree-filter "git checkout a59f75 -- source/_posts/blog1.md source/_posts/blog2.md" master..tmp
```