# Undoing changes to specific files in old commits, leaving no trace of them

Tags: git, version-control, git-revert

I have a branch where I've made some changes to several files, in several commits. Once, a while back, I started doing some work on a subset of these files, and checked in some changes. After that, we decided that these files should be deleted as part of things being done in another branch. Thus, I want to "untouch" those files - they're not relevant to what I do in my branch anymore, and I don't want to cause any merge conflicts with the elsewhere deleted files because of this.

Is there any way I can update the commit that made those changes to leave those files untouched, *and outside the history of my branch*?

**In more concrete terms:**

Consider the following source tree, in the current state:

```
src/A.java
src/B.java
src/C.java
src/D.java
```

Some 10 commits back or so in the history, a commit was made that made changes in the following manner:

```
M   src/B.java
M   src/C.java
A   src/D.java
```

Is there a way I can remove the changes to `C.java` from the history, so that when you look at the commit above it instead looks like

```
M   src/B.java
A   src/D.java
```

As you see, it will appear so that `C.java` has never been touched by my branch.

I've looked at `git revert`, but haven't been able to figure out a way to do it that without creating a new commit, which resets the changes made by the old one. I know I could also avoid merge conflicts by simply deleting the files in my branch as well, but that feels like an "ugly" solution that works this time but maybe not the next (what if the change in the other branch is not deletion, but modification?), so if there's a cleaner way I'd like to learn it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git: best way to remove all changes from a given file for one branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751928/git-best-way-to-remove-all-changes-from-a-given-file-for-one-branch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although <strike>[the now deleted answer by RyPeck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17531419/38055)</strike> RyPeck [linked to a good way of doing this using `git filter-branch`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751928/git-best-way-to-remove-all-changes-from-a-given-file-for-one-branch) in the comments, I solved it differently, so  I thought I'd share how I did it - if for no other purposes, then as a reference for future me (who will inevitably have to ask the Internet this question again, probably soon...):

First, I did an interactive rebase using `git rebase -i master`. That opened up my text editor (I happen to have git configured to open Notepad++) with a file similar to this:

```
pick First commit message
pick Second commit message
pick This is where I touched the files I didn't want to touch
pick Another commit
pick This goes on for a while
pick I think you get the point
pick I'll stop now
```

followed by some comments about how to edit the file. What I did, was to change the line with the commit I wanted to alter to

```
...
edit This is where I touched the files I didn't want to touch
...
```

and then save and close the editor. What happens then is that git applies the three first commits, then stops and says

```
Stopped at <hash>... This is where I touched the files I didn't want to touch
You can amend the commit now, with

    git commit --amend

Once you are satisfied with your changes, run

    git rebase --continue
```

Then, I reset the files to the state they were prior to this commit, using something similar to

```
git reset HEAD^ src/C.java # undoes the changes to the file
git add src/C.java         # stages the undoing of the changes
git commit --amend         # amends the undoing to the last commit
```

After that, the commit has changed the file twice - first the change I made, and then back again - and git has squashed these two sets of changes into one, in which they cancel out and do nothing. I now run

```
git rebase --continue
```

to finish the job. If I now look at the history of `src/C.java`, there's nothing about this set of commits.

This technique is extremely flexible - using the `edit` mode of a commit, you can do any change you want to it.

Comment: This would be a big pain for a large project history. Just for discussions sake, how much does this differ from what `git filter-branch` ends up doing?

Comment: @IamReck: I don't know - I didn't find your answer until I had already done this, so I haven't had the opportunity to test `git filter-branch` and see what would happen. If I have time, I might check out a dummy branch and run a few tests.

Comment: @IamReck: Also, with respect to a "large project history": this is definitely not something I'd recommend doing on a larger scale, or on anything that has been shared among multiple developers. In my case I had worked, alone, on a feature branch, and decided that some of the changes should really be in their branch, since they were part of a different feature. So my changes were all on a local, unpublished branch - such branch histories are (hopefully) never humongous...

Comment: I wasn't doing git filter-branch properly. I found the correct way to do it here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751928/git-best-way-to-remove-all-changes-from-a-given-file-for-one-branch